# How to shrink edges with angle in a mesh?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, transforms, edges, cloth-simulation

I'm struggling to find a way for this problem.

I have a mesh with cloth simulation applied, I want only the upper edges to shrink angle mantaining the same radius and center so it makes the effect of a folded curtain. I have seen Blenderguru make this linearly scaling the upper edges using shape keys but don't know how to do it with curved edges.
In the first picture is a scheme of the way I want it to be.
The second picture is the idea taken from blenderguru tutorial.
I'm stuck and a response would be terrific. Thank you in advance.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a *Curve* modifier?

[image]

Comment: Heeey thank you very much you saved my day, didn't know the functionallity of this tool, have to check it out!

Comment: Used curve modifier and worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome, nice that you succeed on the first try  ;)